# Fed Balance Sheet : flow of funds 2023-04-26

Tags: federal-reserve

## Fed Balance Sheet Changes

Here's a chart of the Fed Balance Sheet changes for 2023-04-26:

[image]

## Flow of funds

Here's some guesses as to how the funds flowed between items:

```
TGA            -> MBS            17.27        MBS rolloff has to come from TGA
LOANS          -> OTHER DEPOSITS  8.67        Loans went to other deposits
OTHER DEPOSITS -> TGA                ?        TGA grew by funds flowing from other deposits

REPO ???
RRP  ???
```

## Question

Can more deductions be made about the flow of funds? For example Repo and RRP?

For example, we see RRP shrank. But, where did that money go? To TGA? to Other deposits?

## Charts

Links to the above charts. You can hover over each item to get the value.

ASSETS:
https://quickchart.io/chart-maker/view/sf-028a3bb4-69fe-4acb-89ea-dd57452c434e

LIABILITIES:
https://quickchart.io/chart-maker/view/sf-aedee69c-255a-439c-ab1c-3a5222a41458